# How can I change the user while using the Facebook C# sdk on Windows Phone?

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, dll, windows-phone

I've started using the C# facebook sdk in my WP7 app, and it works, but I can only log in once. I have a class that opens a web browser and loads a facebook login page. I type in my info, and it does what I want it to do. But once I try to log in again, it remembers the info I gave it earlier, and I can't test other facebook accounts. Does anyone know how to clear my old data so I can log in with another account?

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform Logout operation for performing login operation with another account try this code for performing logout.

```
public partial class LogoutPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private Uri navigateUrl;
    public FacebookOAuthResult FacebookOAuthResult { get; private set; }

    public LogoutPage()
    {
        var appId = "173963872698818";
        string[] extendedPermissions = new[] { "user_about_me", "offline_access" };
        var oauth = new FacebookOAuthClient { AppId = appId };

        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { "response_type", "token" },
                    { "display", "wap" }    //"popup works, touch not works
                };

        if (extendedPermissions != null && extendedPermissions.Length > 0)
        {
            var scope = new StringBuilder();
            scope.Append(string.Join(",", extendedPermissions));
            parameters["scope"] = scope.ToString();
        }

        var loginUrl = oauth.GetLoginUrl(parameters);
        var logoutParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
                                       {
                                           { "next", loginUrl }
                                       };            

        //Redirect to the following url.
        // https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=YOUR_URL&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
        //this.navigateUrl = oauth.GetLogoutUrl(logoutParameters);

        var a = App.Current as App;
        string absoluteURI = " https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=http://www.fengshuiexplorer.host56.com&access_token=" + a.myToken;

        this.navigateUrl = new Uri(absoluteURI);

        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(this.navigateUrl);
    }

    private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        FacebookOAuthResult result;
        if (FacebookOAuthResult.TryParse(e.Uri, out result))
        {
            this.FacebookOAuthResult = result;
            var a = App.Current as App;
            a.isLoggedIn = false;
            NavigationService.GoBack();
        }
        else
        {
            this.FacebookOAuthResult = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try to call below code snippets before you log in again.

```
await new WebBrowser().ClearCookiesAsync();
```